# Отличие Java от Java Android

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Изучаю самостоятельно программирование на Android, очень нравится, получается. Хочу записаться на курсы. Есть курсы просто Java (выбор больше), а есть Java программирование на Android (выбор меньше). Хотелось бы узнать: сильно ли отличаются эти два направления языка? Если выберу просто Java поможет ли мне это в разработке приложений Android (в описании есть пункт "Создание программ с графическим интерфейсом", но не уверен, что это про Android) и что лучше "в жизни"? Прошу меня не пинать, что вопрос не технического характера, очень хочется знать мнение Вас, специалистов. Спасибо.

Comment: Язык java общий для всего, а вот библиотеки отличаются. Имхо сначала всегда язык учится, а потом библиотеки.

Comment: По моему опыту необязательно сначала учить яву, а потом андроид. Можно изучить Java учась писать под андроид. А отличия есть - 8 версию языка только-только начинают внедрять на андроид и графический интерфейс в андроиде отличается от просто Java. Ну и в Android множество своих нюансов. Имхо - нравится и хочется на Android - идите на эти курсы. Хотя, опять таки, ИМХО - курсы не нужны)

Comment: Угу, я вообще считаю что главное - алгоритмы и общее понятие программирования, а язык учится на базовом уровне за пару дней.

Answer (score 3):

Если вопрос переформулировать, то он бы звучал:
"Чем отличается Java от Java?"
Но в подробностях выясняется, что вам просто интересно отличие, Java от Android.
Это совершенно другой вопрос, и ещё более некорректный. И очень не подходит для концепции данного ресурса, но всё же:

> Хотелось бы узнать: сильно ли отличаются эти два направления языка?

Android это не язык, это инструмент для разработки. В будущем, возможно вы будете писать в нем на разных языках и использовать разные структуры С/С++, Java, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, XML, JSON, Groovy, Kotlin да и в целом там есть инъекция, спасибо ребятам из Jetbrains.

> "Создание программ с графическим интерфейсом"

Очень сильное отличие в наработке графического интерфейса между Android и чистой Java.

> и что лучше "в жизни"?

Кроме вас самих, на данный вопрос никто не даст конкретный ответ. Мб вам нельзя сидеть за компьютером по состоянию здоровья)

### В итоге:

Очень сильно отличие в направлении Java и Android, но основания движущая сила в Android это Java, а значит и очень много общего. 
Поэтому ответ такой: Если вы уверены, что будете заниматься разработкой под Android, быстрей переходите на Android и местами подтягиваете Java (Вам просто придется это сделать). Если нет, то есть смысл углубить свои знания Java вначале, а потом сделать выбор в одном из многих направлений.